# How to set the inividual data source of a pipline resolver function via CLI Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am deploying my GraphQL API via Amplify. I added another function to one of the pipeline resolvers and added it to the appropriate slot. This all works. But now this function has to be assigned to another data source.

How can I do that via the configuration files in the console to push the changes via Amplify?

Comment: I have the same issue and reported it on GitHub: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/10094